# how to take a picture with opencv and visualize the webcam at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

In the following code I show in a `QLabel` the web cam of the pc.
However, when trying to take a picture with the `self.boton1` button, he does not take the picture.
`Self.boton1` is connected to the`def take ()`function which is the function I use to take a picture.

But it does not work I hope you can help me:

Try placing `self.boton1.clicked.connect (self.take (self.capture))` inside the `setup_camera ()` function to pass as an argument to the `take ()` function the data you capture `self. capture` but it does not work

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
import cv2
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import uic


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("f.ui",self)

        self.boton1.clicked.connect(self.take)
        self.video_size = QtCore.QSize(320,240)
        self.setup_camera()


        uic.loadUi("f.ui",self)
    def setup_camera(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,self.video_size.height())
        #self.Bfoto.clicked.connect(lambda:self.take(self.capture))

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.display_video_stream)
        self.timer.start(30)

    def display_video_stream(self):
        _,frame  =self.capture.read()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
        image = QtGui.QImage(frame,frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0],frame.strides[0],QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def take(self):
        print("value")
        cap = videoCapture(0)
        leido,frame = cap.read()

        if leido ==True:
            cv2.imwrite("photo.png",frame)
            print("ok")
        else:
            print("error")
        cap.release()
app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

f.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>671</width>
    <height>519</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="boton1">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>530</x>
      <y>400</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>foto</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>100</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>481</width>
      <height>311</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>TextLabel</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>671</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I hope that by pressing the `self.boton` button, the`def take ()`function is triggered and take a picture

Answer (score 0):

> Problem

There is mainly two problem with your python code.
1. you are loading f.ui two times in init() block

```
def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    uic.loadUi("f.ui",self)

    self.boton1.clicked.connect(self.take)
    self.video_size = QtCore.QSize(320,240)
    self.setup_camera()


    uic.loadUi("f.ui",self)
```

So in second uic.loadUi() very previous initialization getting wipe out thats why your button click event is not working.

2.

```
def take(self):
    print("value")
    cap = videoCapture(0)
    leido,frame = cap.read()

    if leido ==True:
        cv2.imwrite("photo.png",frame)
        print("ok")
    else:
        print("error")
    cap.release()
```

In this block you can use the previous self.capture object so that you can work on only one object it makes it simple. And since this object should only release when you are exiting from this program you need not use cap.release() here

> Solution

1. Remove the second uic.loadui() line from your code

   def **init**(self):
       QMainWindow.**init**(self)
       uic.loadUi("f.ui",self)

   ```
   self.boton1.clicked.connect(self.take)
   self.video_size = QtCore.QSize(320,240)
   self.setup_camera()
   #uic.loadUi("f.ui",self)
   ```
2. take() block should be like this

   print("value")
       cap = self.capture
       leido,frame = cap.read()

   ```
   if leido ==True:
       cv2.imwrite("photo.png",frame)
       print("ok")
   else:
       print("error")
       cap.release()
   ```

Comment: Miltra. new error: `file "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\s.py", line 30, in display_video_stream
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0)  C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'`

Comment: @kousikMiltra new error :`C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'`

Comment: which version of opencv are you using? And can you send me the code block of "display_video_stream"?